# UWP - Song recognition through cortana?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, cortana

I've tried to search far and wide but I've only found tutorials covering basic voice commands for cortana, does anyone know if uwp has support for the song recognition within cortana?

Answer (score 0):

You can identify music using Cortana directly. Click on the Microphone button to trigger a voice search with Cortana. Next, click on the Music Note button displayed at the top-right corner:

[image]

Cortana will listen to the song and search for a match in Microsoft's online music database. Once done, it will display the name of the song, along with a link to purchase it on the Windows Store

If you want your app have able to recognize songs, you may need to create your own song recognition [service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service). Because 
Cortana does not provide song recognition services currently.